# Windows defender removing vba code from Word Document

Tags: vba, ms-word, windows-defender

We have a large word application with around 100 forms, 50 modules and 20 classes.  Over 100 people get into this application and some of them are seasonal which means that they will use different computers.  We are running into an issue where windows defender seems to be removing the the vba from the word document.  It seems to only happened every once in a while and we believe it is with someone new to the application.  Each time it occurs, the file is broken and we have to use our copy to save over the original version.  The size of the file will go from 6,897KB to like 60KB.  Below are screen shots that I was able to get from one user that caused this issue.  Any assistance on how to prevent this from happening would be greatly appreciated.

This is the first error the user receives when they try to open the word document: [image: FirstError]

This is the error that the user receives after they click on the "First Error":
 [image: NextError]

Comment: maybe consider not including a Trojan Downloader in your word doc?

Comment: If the application has a trojan downloader then why does it work 99% of the time.  It is only the rare few that this is happening and only new users but not all new users.  I think the windows defender  only on a few computers is some how falsely believing that this application has a trojan downloader but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: I would like some way to block window defender from reducing the size of this word application.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/filesubmission

Comment: For all I know your word doc has an embedded virus which is pretty well hidden and only unpacks itself under very particular circumstances.  It could even be that when these specific users go to open it, something on their machine (which hasn't been caught) is attaching itself to that document and is tripping Defender.  Or, it might be that you are doing something that under certain conditions looks pretty close to what that virus does and Defender is finally catching it.  Honestly, no one here is going to be able to diagnose it without access to the file - and I wouldn't touch it myself.

Comment: Codes are signed with didgital certificate (added to Trusted Publisher if not global recognised)? Perhaps on first launch, the macro checks and download additional required files which behaves just like trojan downloader? How do you deploy the macro (Word Application)? Assuming it's a .docm file, may better to convert it to .dotm? We can't just use imagination without seeing the code.

Comment: The application is a couple thousands lines of code so it is hard to post.  The file is a .docm file.  Why is a .dotm better?  Thank you for your help!